# Can I selectively turn constraints off?

Tags: validation, grails

I have a domain class which gets updated from the UI. It was some constraints to enforce that the users fill in all the required information and all is well.

However, I also have some quartz jobs which update the domain and they do not necessarily need to adhere to all those constraints. I'd like to ignore specific ones so that `save()` works.

There are a couple of ways I can think of doing this:

- Use `save(validate: false)` but then that will ignore all the constraints (not exactly what I want)
- Remove the constraints which only apply to the UI and manually check that the data is valid in the controller
- Wrap these constraints into validators which only kick in if the value of a transient property is `saveFromUI` (set this transient property from the controller before `save()`)

These all seems as hacks. Any other (better) ways?

Answer (score 2):

Almost sounds like you need to consider using a command object.

However, you can always specify which properties to validate in your case of update. So something like this:

```
myDomainInstance.validate(['prop1', 'prop2'])
...
myDomainInstance.save(validate: false) // since you already have done so manually prior to this.
```

The documentation has more information about [validation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html).